# What does the notation $|+\rangle,|−\rangle,|±i \rangle$ mean in Bloch sphere?

Tags: bloch-sphere

The axis in a a 2D diagram like the following, usually represent 2 quantities. Eg in pic below, $x$ represents time and $y$ represents velocity

[image]

What gets measured along each axis of a Bloch sphere? In other words what do the different axis of Bloch sphere represent? I read that $z$ is $|0⟩$ or $|1⟩$ (spin), $x$ is $|+⟩$ or $|-⟩$ and $y$ is $|i⟩$ or $|-i⟩$. But what do they mean?

[image]

Comment: are you asking what the notation $|+\rangle,|-\rangle,|\pm i\rangle$ means?

Comment: yes please. Could you explain?

Answer (score 3):

The standard definition of $|\pm\rangle$ and $|\pm i\rangle$ is:
$$|+\rangle \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle),
\qquad |-\rangle \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle-|1\rangle).\\
\qquad |+i\rangle \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle+i|1\rangle),
\qquad |-i\rangle \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle-i|1\rangle).$$
These are the eigenstates of the Pauli operators $X$ and $Y$, respectively, and thus are represented in the Bloch sphere on the corresponding axes.

Answer (score 1):

I think its best if we start with the state $|\psi⟩ = \alpha |0⟩ + \beta |1⟩$. Since we know that the total probability is 1 ($|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2 = 1 $), we can plot $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as a circle with radius 1 centered at (0,0) (In the figure below let $x$ be $\alpha$ and $y$ be $\beta$ or vice versa). Therefore, all the possible combination for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ lies in the perimeter of this circle. Now, instead of using $(x,y)$ coordinates to plot the probabilities of  $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we can instead use the angle formed using polar coordinates (In the figure below that would be $(r,\theta)=(1,\theta)$).

[image: Circle with radius 1]

In quantum computing however, operators may change more than the probability of the basis but also other stuff such as the phase. Therefore, in general, it is easier to represent a state in the following form:
$|\psi⟩ = cos(\frac{\theta}{2}) |0⟩ + e^{i \phi} sin(\frac{\theta}{2}) |1⟩$

Notice that there is a second angle in play now. This means to plot the possible states, a 3D plot of the surface of a ball is needed which is the Bloch sphere. To read more about the derivation of the Bloch sphere, look at [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/205209/284967) answer.

Now, to answer the question, in my understanding, **the $(x,y,z)$ axis of the plot is merely an arbitrary axis. The main information held in the plot lies in the polar coordinates $(1, \theta, \phi)$.**

It is not that $z$ measures $|0⟩$ or $|1⟩$, but instead the states $|0⟩$ and $|1⟩$ happen to lie in the $z$ axis. Similarly for the other 2 axes.